# Apache 2.4: how to show an index of files and directories?

Tags: apache-2.4

I'd like to configure Apache 2.4 so that where an index.html doesn't exist, the browser will display a listing of files and directories.

I have mod_dir and mod_autoindex installed and activated.

This is my config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.localdev
    Servername mysite.localdev


    <Directory /var/www/mysite.localdev>
        AllowOverride none
        FallbackResource /index.php
        Require all granted
        Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews      
    </Directory>


    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/var/run/php/mysite.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/mysite.localdev
    DirectoryIndex index.php /index.php


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.localdev.error-log
    

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.localdev.access-log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your config seems correct, except you don't set explicit + or - in all Options, only for the first (Indexes). From what I have read in doc, it could be an issue. Try +Indexes +Follow ...

Comment: I've prefixed '+' to all the Options parameters and restarted. No listing shows.

Comment: Load modules mod_info, then browse to /server-info/ and see what is loaded. And what do the logs say?

Comment: @Bib loaded modules: http://pastie.org/p/7h8TInkGGbYJ1E5XfVuUl9. Regarding logs: what exactly should I be looking for in the logs?

Comment: Errors, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Bib: I'm not seeing any errors related to the issue.  I've described the problem in the the post here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1080066/apache-2-4-how-to-show-an-index-of-files-and-directories